# select every second element in a row with 3 items

Tags: html, css, sass

I have my code like this:

```
<div class='container'>
    <!-- row 1 -->
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <!- row 2 -->
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <!-- row 3 -->
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

I want to target these items using css only.
I want the first item or each row to have a border red, the second item with border purple and the third item with border yellow for example.
So it should be something like this:

```
<div class='container'>
    <!-- row 1 -->
    <div class='item'>{item with red border}</div>
    <div class='item'>{item with purple border}</div>
    <div class='item'>{item with yellow border}</div>
    <!- row 2 -->
    <div class='item'>{item with red border}</div>
    <div class='item'>{item with purple border}</div>
    <div class='item'>{item with yellow border}</div>
    <!-- row 3 -->
    <div class='item'>{item with red border}</div>
    <div class='item'>{item with purple border}</div>
    <div class='item'>{item with yellow border}</div>
    <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

How can I do this?
I was thinking of using something like `:nth-child(2n)` but this doesn't work, it just works on every other item so I'm looking for another solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I do this? I was thinking of using something like
>   :nth-child(2n) but this doesn't work

You are thinking just right. `nth-child` should do the job. However, you need to calculate the pattern.

How does this work? `Xn+Y` works by using `n` placeholder as the elements starting from `0`.

So, `3n+2` will target starting from `3 x 0 + 2 = 2`, `3 x 1 + 2 = 5`, and so on. This will target your purple divs. 
Similarly, `3n+1` will target `3x0+1 = 1`, `3x1+1 = 4`, and so on. 
Lastly, `3n+3` is equivalent to just `3n`.

```css
div.item { margin: 4px; }
div.item:nth-child(3n+1) { border: 1px solid red; }
div.item:nth-child(3n+2) { border: 1px solid blue; }
div.item:nth-child(3n) { border: 1px solid yellow; }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <!-- row 1 -->
    <div class='item'>{item with red border}</div>
    <div class='item'>{item with purple border}</div>
    <div class='item'>{item with yellow border}</div>
    <!- row 2 -->
    <div class='item'>{item with red border}</div>
    <div class='item'>{item with purple border}</div>
    <div class='item'>{item with yellow border}</div>
    <!-- row 3 -->
    <div class='item'>{item with red border}</div>
    <div class='item'>{item with purple border}</div>
    <div class='item'>{item with yellow border}</div>
    <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! Just curious, how exactly does the -3n work?

Comment: `-3 x 1 + 7` = `-3 + 7` = `4`; `-3 x 2 + 7` = `-6 + 7` = `1`. and so on. However, in this case `3n+1` would suffice. Have changed the code to make it simpler using `3n+1`.

Answer (score 2):

As you have 3 items per row, you need to do `3n +` the number you need:

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

/* every first item of 3 item row */
.container div:nth-child(3n+1) {
  border-color: red;
}

/* every second item of 3 item row */
.container div:nth-child(3n+2) {
  border-color: purple;
}

/* every third item of 3 item row */
.container div:nth-child(3n+3) {
  border-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <!-- row 1 -->
  <div class='item'>{item with red border}</div>
  <div class='item'>{item with purple border}</div>
  <div class='item'>{item with yellow border}</div>
  <!- row 2 -->
  <div class='item'>{item with red border}</div>
  <div class='item'>{item with purple border}</div>
  <div class='item'>{item with yellow border}</div>
  <!-- row 3 -->
  <div class='item'>{item with red border}</div>
  <div class='item'>{item with purple border}</div>
  <div class='item'>{item with yellow border}</div>
  <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Comment: Shoot! 10s too late. Was about to hit the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item:nth-child(3n+1){
       border:2px solid red;
    }
    
    .item:nth-child(3n+2){
       border:2px solid purple;
    }
    
    .item:nth-child(3n+3){
       border:2px solid yellow;
       margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <!-- row 1 -->
    <div class='item'>a</div>
    <div class='item'>b</div>
    <div class='item'>c</div>
    <!- row 2 -->
    <div class='item'>a</div>
    <div class='item'>b</div>
    <div class='item'>c</div>
    <!-- row 3 -->
    <div class='item'>a</div>
    <div class='item'>b</div>
    <div class='item'>c</div>
    <!-- etc -->
</div>
```